# Postgresql extension intarray uniq

Tags: sql, postgresql

My sql structure has a field which is array.
The value is

```
{5010011,5010031,5010041,5010081}
```

I execute a query.

```
Update users 
  set faces=uniq(array_cat(faces,ARRAY[5010011,5010031,5010041,5010081]))
```

I get the result is

```
{5010011,5010031,5010041,5010081,5010011,5010031,5010041,5010081}
```

I use the uniq() function, but it does not work. I want to remove the duplicate value in array.

Answer (score 1):

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/intarray.html)

> `uniq(int[])  int[]`  remove **adjacent** duplicates

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

So it only removes duplicates that are adjacent (a value immediately followed by the same value).

The manual also shows how to use the function: you need to sort the array first, so that the duplicate values wind up next to each other: `uniq(sort('{1,2,3,2,1}'::int[]))`

So in your case:

```
Update users 
  set  faces = uniq(
                   sort(array_cat(faces, ARRAY[5010011,5010031,5010041,5010081]))
                   )
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply. I don't sort the array. So the uniq function is not work.

Comment: @WongManlok: well, you **have** to sort the array before applying the `uniq()` function as I have shown in my answer. The better solution however would be to normalize your data model and then create a proper unique index